# Auto brightness not working correctly on Macbook Pro 13" 2015

Tags: screen, auto-brightness

I have problem with set up auto brightness. Everything was fine until I didn't pushed brightness button on keyboard. Now system report says that auto brightness settings are not working but in Preferences everything is set up correctly. Of course, my auto brightness settings are working fine. But why system report says that it is not?

I have also tried to reset SMC NVRAM and PRAM but it is not working.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I believe my problem is the same. MacBook Pro Mid 2014. The computer should not display auto brightness as an option, if it does not exist. And as far as I'm aware, it does exist on all modern MacBook pros. Will let you know if I figure it out.